# Why does Apache send HTTP/1.1 when client requests HTTP/1.0? And many other very similar problems

Tags: apache-2.4, http

Apache sends HTTP/1.1 when client requests HTTP/1.0? Why?  So the request is:

```
Connected to example.com port 80
GET / HTTP/1.0
```

The response is similar to:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
```

It says HTTP/1.1 in the response. But why?

To try by yourself, just do the same request.

Update (using port 80); Are all these responses correct?:

Request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Request (if Host: is missing, then 400 Bad Request):

```
GET / HTTP/2.0
Host: example.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Request (HTTP/3 not supported in Apache; if Host: is missing, then 400 Bad Request, works till HTTP/9.9):

```
GET / HTTP/3.0
Host: example.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Request:

```
GET / HTTP/2
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Request:

```
GET / HTTP/3
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: The logic is probably that anything that is NOT version HTTP/1.0 must be at least HTTP/1.1 compliant and include the `Host:` header.

Comment: @HermanB that thing is done in server/protocol.c in apache's source. You can see the source right now by going to httpd.apache.org and downloading apache's source.

Answer (score 2):

That is completely by design and as expected when your server isn’t configured yet to support HTTP/2 and/or you’re not connecting with a HTTP/2 capable client.

[RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.1) requires that HTTP servers always begin their responses with the highest HTTP version that they claim to support.

That HTTP version can be different from what the client used in their request. Over the non-binary telnet connection the best that Apache can support  will be HTTP/1.1

Note that Apache (and other web servers ) should limit the other aspects of their response to the capabilities both the client and server mutually support though. When you make HTTP/1.0 requests Apache for example should not use response codes that were not part of the HTTP/1.0 spec such as the code “100” “Continue”.

Comment: My server has support for HTTP/2.

Comment: But I accessed it using port 80. `GET / HTTP/2` throws error. `GET / HTTP/5.0\r\nHost: example.com` works?? seriously?

Comment: Apache supports HTTP/1.0? right?

Comment: But you can’t support http/2 on port 80

Comment: HTTP2 clear text is supported on port 80 right? Why does `HTTP/5.0` work though? But not `HTTP/5`.

Comment: Even `GET /` works LOL WHAT!